# Transfer with different sized state spaces in neural networks/deep reinforcement learning

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

Say we are transferring sequentially from environment 1-3 below, where the text corresponding to each environment describes its observation space.

Env 1 observation: 
position of robot

Env 2 observation:
position of robot, position of object 1, velocity of object 1

Env 3 observation:
position of robot, position of object 1, velocity of object 1, position of object 2

How do we setup the architecture for the value/policy network such that it can handle variable length observations like this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a fragment embedding network $E(x, l; \theta)$ which takes as input a small fragment of the state $x$ (such as the position), the type of information given $l$ (position, or velocity, etc) and outputs some $d$ dimensional vector.
2. Choose some aggregation function $g$ which combines an arbitrary number of embeddings into a fixed size representation. This can be simple as $g(x_1, \ldots x_n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum x_i$, or perhaps an LSTM $g(x_i; \phi)$.
3. Take the output of $g$ as your state embedding.